# ASP.NET MVC 2 Data Validation: Make C# Regex work for both C# and JavaScript simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I have this C# regex:

```
^\s?((?<qty>\d+)\s?/)?\s?[$]?\s?(?<price>\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s?$
```

and use MVC's data validation at the client.  JavaScript says this regex is invalid, although C# works perfectly fine.  Any idea how to get it to work for both C# and JavaScript, since it doesn't seem possible to provide a separate JavaScript Regex in the Data Validation annotations?

The regex validates a quantity and price.  4/$2.69 for example.

Comment: You're not using it, but JavaScript doesn't support look behind which is supported by C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support named reference `(?<…>…)`. You need to use

```
^\s?((\d+)\s?/)?\s?[$]?\s?(\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s?$
```

and refer `qty` and `price` as `1` and `2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the group names (`<qty>`).